# Minimal custom permalink structure

Tags: permalinks, seo

I'm aware that there are posts discussing this issue already (e.g. [What is the best permalink structure for SEO?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1364/what-is-the-best-permalink-structure-for-seo)) but I have a specific set of requirements according to my wordpress site structure, namely:

1. 6 pages
2. A small number of posts (~ 3 at launch, maybe 1 new one per month)

I'd like to include the post name in the URL (for both SEO and easier stats analysis), but I've seen references to 'problems' arising from using *just* the post name.

- Would this be the case, even on such a small site?
- Would `/%post_id%/%$postname%/` be a 'better' alternative? I notice that, even with this configuration, the Pages don't use the post_id in their URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi **@Bobby Jack*:*

**You'll have absolutely zero problem** given your number of pages and posts.  If you were looking at 5000, 10k, 25k pages or more, then start to worry.

And the real problem is with categories as the URL base in the current implementation of WordPress' URL routing (which I hope to see changed in v3.2 or v3.3):

- [**Category in Permalinks Considered Harmful**](http://ottopress.com/2010/category-in-permalinks-considered-harmful/)

**In Summary, nothing to worry about.**

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the permalink settings in the WP admin only apply to posts, and not to pages. With pages, you can create your own hierarchy by creating new pages as child pages. By choosing what "slugs" you use for each page, you define the hierarchy. Posts are teated separately.